# Record screen with input and output audio using with C# SharpAvi and NAudio

Tags: c#, video-capture, audio-recording, naudio

I m trying to making an application which can record the screen and at the same time can record the input and output audio. I checked so many things on web but couldt find anything that can do it together.

I tried to do something with sharpavi and naudio. The code at the bottom can record the screen with the voice that come from microphone and also record the voice that come from speakers too. The problem is screen video and audio that come from microphone creates a video file and the voice that coming from spearkes creates other mp3 file. (if my boss would want to do something this way i couldnt do :)

So i want create my video file with included sreeen record, input and output voice together. I hope you can help me.

```
        private readonly int screenWidth;
        private readonly int screenHeight;

        private readonly AviWriter writer;
        private readonly IAviVideoStream videoStream;
        private readonly IAviAudioStream audioStream;

        private readonly WaveInEvent audioSource;
        private readonly Thread screenThread;

        private readonly ManualResetEvent stopThread = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        private readonly AutoResetEvent videoFrameWritten = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        private readonly AutoResetEvent audioBlockWritten = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        WasapiLoopbackCapture capture = new WasapiLoopbackCapture();
        WaveFileWriter writerx;

        public Recorder(string fileName,
            FourCC codec, int quality,
            int audioSourceIndex, SupportedWaveFormat audioWaveFormat, bool encodeAudio, int audioBitRate)
        {
            System.Windows.Media.Matrix toDevice;
            using (var source = new HwndSource(new HwndSourceParameters()))
            {
                toDevice = source.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice;
            }

            screenWidth = (int)Math.Round(SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth * toDevice.M11);
            screenHeight = (int)Math.Round(SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight * toDevice.M22);

            // Create AVI writer and specify FPS
            writer = new AviWriter(fileName)
            {
                FramesPerSecond = 10,
                EmitIndex1 = true,
            };

            // Create video stream
            videoStream = CreateVideoStream(codec, quality);
            videoStream.Name = "Screencast";


            var outputFolder = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "NAudio");
            Directory.CreateDirectory(outputFolder);
            var outputFilePath = Path.Combine(outputFolder, "recordedx.wav");

            writerx = new WaveFileWriter(outputFilePath, capture.WaveFormat);

            if (audioSourceIndex >= 0)
            {
                while (capture.CaptureState != NAudio.CoreAudioApi.CaptureState.Stopped)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                }


                var waveFormat = ToWaveFormat(audioWaveFormat);
                audioStream = CreateAudioStream(waveFormat, encodeAudio, audioBitRate);
                audioStream.Name = "Voice";

                audioSource = new WaveInEvent
                {
                    DeviceNumber = audioSourceIndex,
                    WaveFormat = waveFormat,
                    BufferMilliseconds = (int)Math.Ceiling(1000 / writer.FramesPerSecond),
                    NumberOfBuffers = 3,
                };

                audioSource.DataAvailable += audioSource_DataAvailable;
                capture.DataAvailable += Capture_DataAvailable;   //     
            }

            screenThread = new Thread(RecordScreen)
            {
                Name = typeof(Recorder).Name + ".RecordScreen",
                IsBackground = true
            };

            if (audioSource != null)
            {
                videoFrameWritten.Set();
                audioBlockWritten.Reset();
                audioSource.StartRecording();
                capture.StartRecording();//
            }

            screenThread.Start();
        }

        private void Capture_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
        {
                writerx.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
        }

        private IAviVideoStream CreateVideoStream(FourCC codec, int quality)
        {

            if (codec == KnownFourCCs.Codecs.Uncompressed)
            {
                return writer.AddUncompressedVideoStream(screenWidth, screenHeight);
            }
            else if (codec == KnownFourCCs.Codecs.MotionJpeg)
            {
                return writer.AddMotionJpegVideoStream(screenWidth, screenHeight, quality);
            }
            else
            {
                return writer.AddMpeg4VideoStream(screenWidth, screenHeight, (double)writer.FramesPerSecond,

                    quality: quality,
                    codec: codec,
                   forceSingleThreadedAccess: true);
            }
        }

        private IAviAudioStream CreateAudioStream(WaveFormat waveFormat, bool encode, int bitRate)
        {

            if (encode)
            {

                return writer.AddMp3AudioStream(waveFormat.Channels, waveFormat.SampleRate, bitRate);
            }
            else
            {
                return writer.AddAudioStream(
                    channelCount: waveFormat.Channels,
                    samplesPerSecond: waveFormat.SampleRate,
                    bitsPerSample: waveFormat.BitsPerSample);
            }
        }

        private static WaveFormat ToWaveFormat(SupportedWaveFormat waveFormat)
        {
            switch (waveFormat)
            {
                case SupportedWaveFormat.WAVE_FORMAT_44M16:
                    return new WaveFormat(44100, 16, 1);
                case SupportedWaveFormat.WAVE_FORMAT_44S16:
                    return new WaveFormat(44100, 16, 2);
                default:
                    throw new NotSupportedException("Wave formats other than '16-bit 44.1kHz' are not currently supported.");
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            stopThread.Set();
            screenThread.Join();

            writerx.Dispose();//
            writerx = null;//
            capture.Dispose();//

            if (audioSource != null)
            {
                audioSource.StopRecording();
                audioSource.DataAvailable -= audioSource_DataAvailable;
            }


            writer.Close();
            stopThread.Close();
        }

        private void RecordScreen()
        {
            var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            var buffer = new byte[screenWidth * screenHeight * 4];

            Task videoWriteTask = null;

            var isFirstFrame = true;
            var shotsTaken = 0;
            var timeTillNextFrame = TimeSpan.Zero;
            stopwatch.Start();

            while (!stopThread.WaitOne(timeTillNextFrame))
            {
                GetScreenshot(buffer);
                shotsTaken++;

                // Wait for the previous frame is written
                if (!isFirstFrame)
                {

                    videoWriteTask.Wait();

                    videoFrameWritten.Set();
                }

                if (audioStream != null)
                {
                    var signalled = WaitHandle.WaitAny(new WaitHandle[] { audioBlockWritten, stopThread });
                    if (signalled == 1)
                        break;
                }


                videoWriteTask = videoStream.WriteFrameAsync(true, buffer, 0, 

                timeTillNextFrame = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(shotsTaken / (double)writer.FramesPerSecond - stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
                if (timeTillNextFrame < TimeSpan.Zero)
                    timeTillNextFrame = TimeSpan.Zero;

                isFirstFrame = false;
            }

            stopwatch.Stop();

            // Wait for the last frame is written
            if (!isFirstFrame)
            {

                videoWriteTask.Wait();

            }
        }

        private void GetScreenshot(byte[] buffer)
        {
            using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(screenWidth, screenHeight))
            using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new System.Drawing.Size(screenWidth, screenHeight));
                var bits = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
                Marshal.Copy(bits.Scan0, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                bitmap.UnlockBits(bits);          
            }
        }

        private void audioSource_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
        {
            var signalled = WaitHandle.WaitAny(new WaitHandle[] { videoFrameWritten, stopThread });
            if (signalled == 0)
            {
                audioStream.WriteBlock(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
                audioBlockWritten.Set();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for capturing video (avi) and audio (speakers):

```
//1) Add projects: Captura.Base, Captura.Bass, Captura.SharpAvi, Screna from this repository:
https://github.com/MathewSachin v8.0.0

//2) Copy bass.dll & bassmix.dll from x64 folder:
//http://www.un4seen.com/files/bassmix24.zip
//http://www.un4seen.com/files/bass24.zip


recordTask = new Task((cancelationToken) =>
{
    var fps = 30;
    var sharpAVICodec = new SharpAviItem(AviCodec.MotionJpeg, "Motion JPEG encoder using WPF's JPG encoder");
    using (var imageProvider = new ImageProvider(height, width, dpiKoeff, rect.Left, rect.Top))
    using (var audioSource = new BassAudioSource(new Captura.AudioSettings()
    {
        Enabled = true,
        PlaybackRecordingRealTime = false,
        Quality = 100,
    }))
    using (var audioProvider = audioSource.GetMixedAudioProvider())
    using (var videoWriter = sharpAVICodec.GetVideoFileWriter(new Captura.Models.VideoWriterArgs()
    {
        FileName = _capturedVideoPath,
        AudioProvider = audioProvider,
        AudioQuality = 70,
        FrameRate = fps,
        ImageProvider = imageProvider,
        VideoQuality = 70
    }))
    using (var recorder = new Recorder(videoWriter, imageProvider, fps, audioProvider))
    {
        //error:
        //foreach(var rs in audioSource.AvailableRecordingSources)
        //    rs.Active = true;

        foreach (var ls in audioSource.AvailableLoopbackSources)
            ls.Active = true;

        recorder.Start();

        while (!recordTaskCancel.IsCancellationRequested)
            Task.Yield();

        recorder.Stop();
    }

    }
}, recordTaskCancel.Token);
recordTask.Start();



internal class ImageProvider : IImageProvider
{
    public ImageProvider(int height, int width, double dpiKoeff, int left, int top)
    {
        Height = height;
        Width = width;
        DPIKoeff = dpiKoeff;
        Left = left;
        Top = top;
    }

    public int Height { get; }
    public int Width { get; }
    public int Left { get; }
    public int Top { get; }
    public double DPIKoeff { get; }

    public IBitmapFrame Capture() => new OneTimeFrame(GetScreenshot(Left, Top, Width, Height));

    public void Dispose(){}

    private Bitmap GetScreenshot(int left, int top, int screenWidth, int screenHeight)
    {
        var bitmap = new Bitmap(screenWidth, screenHeight);
        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            graphics.CopyFromScreen(left, top, 0, 0, new System.Drawing.Size(screenWidth, screenHeight));
            var mousePos = WinProcess.GetMousePosition();
            var mouseDpiAdditionalOffset = -(200.0 - (200.0 * DPIKoeff));
            graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), (float)(mousePos.X - (left / DPIKoeff) + mouseDpiAdditionalOffset), (float)(mousePos.Y - (top / DPIKoeff) + mouseDpiAdditionalOffset), 10, 10);
            graphics.Flush();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
}





[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
internal static extern bool GetCursorPos(ref Win32Point pt);
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct Win32Point
{
    public Int32 X;
    public Int32 Y;
};
public static Point GetMousePosition()
{
    var w32Mouse = new Win32Point();
    GetCursorPos(ref w32Mouse);
    return new Point(w32Mouse.X, w32Mouse.Y);
}
```